# Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->getConnection()->exec() api?

Tags: database, zend-framework, exec

Simply as the tittle says. I can't find an api, documentation nor examples of the exec() api in the getConnection method of the Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract class.

What's the output of a valid/invalid sql script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what adapter you are using.  If you are using `Pdo` then you are simply calling [`PDO::exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) when you call `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->getConnection()->exec()`.

`Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->getConnection()` returns the underlying database connection resource from PHP.  In the case of PDO it is what is returned by calling `new PDO()`.  If you were using Mysqli, then it is the result of calling `new Mysqli()` (Mysqli doesn't have an `exec()` method though).

Answer (score 0):

So I did some self testing and found that:

- Success code returns 0
- Error code throws Exception

I guess there's no other scenario (`code != 0?`).. so I put the entire code inside a try-catch and eval `$code === 0` just in case